# Write script to scrape a site and output its data in JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am stuck at a problem. I want to get a JSON of all of the company listings data for this site.

Each link endpoint holds company-specific data such as ***company name, description, zip code, state, and address***
My initial thinking is:

1. get a list of the site into a list
2. Probably use requests.get again to scrape each individual end point maybe

So far I have tried a few ways, here is my latest attempt:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



base_url = "http://data-interview.enigmalabs.org/companies/"
r = requests.get(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all("a")

link_list = []


for link in links:
  print  link_list.append("<a href='%s'</a>" %(link.get("href")))
```

**I have no idea of how to extract all the data i need from the individual pages**

Comment: And what specifically is your question? This seems rather broad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have no idea of how to extract all the data I need from the individual pages then store then in a JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4, urlparse, json, requests
from os.path import basename as bn

links = [] # the relative paths to companies
data = {} # company name --> company data
base = 'http://data-interview.enigmalabs.org/'

def bs(r): # returns a beautifulsoup table object for the table in the page of the relative path
    return bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urlparse.urljoin(base, r).encode()).content, 'html.parser').find('table')

for i in range(1,11):
    print 'Collecting page %d' % i
    # add end-point links
    links += [a['href'] for a in bs('companies?page=%d' % i).findAll('a')]

for link in links:
    print 'Processing %s' % link
    name = bn(link)
    data[name] = {}
    for row in bs(link).findAll('tr'):
        desc, cont = row.findAll('td')
        data[name][desc.text.encode()] = cont.text.encode()

print json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Wow! really loved your solution. much simpler than I initially thought. Thanks again and  I was able to completely understand your approach as well.